# How to add a service provider in wso2 IS using api?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to  customize the user interface of add a service provider in wso2 IS, so I want to know that how to add a service provider in wso2 IS using api? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add service provider without using management console UI?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server expose Service Provider functionality through web service APIs.

You can use the Service Provider APIs documnted [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Using+the+Service+Provider+API)